# python function start_copy_from_url not triggering Azure storage BlobCreated event for ADF

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

**Objective:**
We are wanting to copy a blob from a source Container to a destination Container using an Azure Function (python)
Once it arrives in the destination Container.. we want to the blob created event to trigger an ADF pipeline

**The Problem**
If i manually copy a file to the destination Container the trigger fires as expected and the ADF pipeline executes successfully.
However if the file is created by the Azure function the trigger doesn't fire.

The python code responsible for the file creation is

```
dest_blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(dest_acct_url, credential=credential)

copied_blob_client = dest_blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=dest_container_name, blob=dest_blob_name)

blob_to_copy_url = blob_url + '?' + sas_token

# Start copy
print('Copy started')
copied_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(blob_to_copy_url)
for i in range(10):
    dest_blob_properties = copied_blob_client.get_blob_properties()
    status = dest_blob_properties.copy.status
    print('Copy destination properties status: ' + status)
    if status == "success":
        # Copy finished
        print('Copy is successful')
        
        break
    time.sleep(10)

if status != 'success':
    # if not finished after 100s, cancel the operation
    dest_blob_properties = copied_blob_client.get_blob_properties()
    print('Copy destination properties status: ' + status)
    copy_id = dest_blob_properties.copy.id
    copied_blob_client.abort_copy(copy_id)
    dest_blob_properties = copied_blob_client.get_blob_properties()
    print('Copy is aborted')
```

Im wondering if there is something to do with the start_copy_from_url function which stops it from triggering the BlobCreated event but i cant seem to find anything on the topic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you make sure if the file is getting created through Azure functions in blob storage?

Comment: yes the file is being created successfully in the destination container.. just seems to be the event not firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if i set the requires_sync attribute to True then it forces it to be syncronous and the BlobCreated event sucessfully triggers

```
copied_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(blob_to_copy_url, requires_sync=True)
```

In my scenario this is an ok option. Would still be great to know if its possible to trigger on Async